# Click handler fires twice on one click

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, click

A page presents a dialog with an OK button.  Under certain circumstances clicking the OK button fires its click-handler twice (event.timeStamp is identical).  Invoking event.stopPropagation() in the click handler did not make the problem go away.

I've 'fixed' the problem by comparing event.timeStamp with its previous value.  That is not a very satisfactory fix.  What else might do the job?

**The Circumstances**
This problem follows relatively minor changes to code that has been running, and evolving, over years.  There is a lot of it, and it would be difficult to pare the thing down to a few lines for illustration.  The changes involved adding a dialog to load tide data for a year other than the current year.  FWIW here's a very brief summary of how the page works.

On opening, it sends a GET request for a year's worth of tidal current data.  Subsequently, a method increments a time, draws a field of vectors appropriate for that time over a NOAA chart, and schedules itself to run after a few seconds.  It iterates in that manner over a time-frame.

The user can define a course, run a vessel along it, and see how current affects its track.  The course definition, which includes a launch time, can be saved (as a cookie) and restored.  If, when attempting to restore a course, available current data don't bracket the launch time, a warning is given and the dialog closes without changing the state of the page.

The user can then open a second dialog to GET the appropriate tide data.  They can then try again to restore the course.  This dialog changes the tide data and parameters describing the time and time-frame.

The problem - two responses to a single click - **occurs only when an attempt to load a course fails, a new dataset is loaded, and a *second* attempt to load a course is initiated**.

On that second attempt, code handling a click on the OK button of the load-the-course dialog gets the same Click event twice.  I conclude it is the "same event" because the timeStamp value is the same. Oddly, the

If the tide data are loaded first, and then the course retrieved, the problem does not arise.

I'm not optimistic about an answer; a detailed description would be impossibly long.  Constructive suggestions welcome.  (event.preventDefault() does not change the behavior.  Did not expect it to, but Due Diligence and all that.)

Comment: Please make a testable example and post the code.

Comment: ***The code***?

Comment: There are thousands of lines of code.  If I knew how to compress it to a useful example, I would.  Much of the code deals with stopping the vector repaint before changing the underlying data, and restarting it in a new timeframe.

Comment: Sounds like you bind event listeners more than once, but impossible to tell since you did not show us any of those billions of lines of code.

Comment: binding twice was exactly the problem.  Thank you. if (!this.initDlg) {    init(); this.init = true;} should have been if (!this.initDlg) {init();this.initDlg = true;}